# Как получить координаты видимой части элемента относительно окна?

Tags: javascript, координаты

Получаю координаты элемента способом `getBoundingClientRect()` `rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left`, но как на JS получить координаты видимой части элемента? Когда часть элемента находится за пределами экрана.

[image: получить координаты видимой части элемента]

Comment: _"на JS получить координаты видимой части элемента"_ -- окно браузера может быть перекрыто другим окном. это из js не определить. т.к. нет доступа к системному API

Comment: Это понятно, нужно получить координаты видимой части элемента, относительно окна, при скроллинге.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/  или http://javascript.ru/ui/offset

Comment: @Stack Это получается не относительно окна, а относительно документа

Answer (score 4):

Как говорил Эйнштейн: "Всё относительно"

Вам нужно получить координаты видимой части элемента только с учетом того, что элемент может не помещаться в родителя?

Тогда допустим ваш элемент "хранится" в переменной `e1`. Берем `e1.getBoundingClientRect()`, потом берем `e1.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()` и находим максимальные значения `left` и `top`, а также минимальные у `right` и `bottom`. Это и есть видимая часть *относительно* непосредственного родителя.

Дальше хуже. Непосредственный родитель вашего элемента может не помещаться в своего родителя или может быть смещен так, что его часть (и, может быть, часть вашего элемента) не видна. Это не страшно, берем всех родителей вплоть до `document.documentElement` и среди них находим максимальные и минимальные значения соответствующих параметров. Но бывают еще абсолютно позиционированные элементы и элементы с фиксированным положением относительно окна браузера. Они могут находиться в иерархии документа где угодно. Часть из них может быть скрыта или прозрачна и это нужно учитывать при обнаружении "окна видимости". С этим придется бороться только путем перебора всех элементов (ну пожалуй кроме дочерних, хотя нет, есть же `z-index`)

Наконец ваш элемент может сидеть в `<iframe>` страницы с другого домена или быть перекрытым например каким-нибудь флешем. Вот это уже эпик фейл. Обнаружить видно ваш элемент или нет и если видно, то какую именно часть - **невозможно**.

Вот. Возможность решения вашей задачи зависит от полноты ее трактовки и входных условий.

Comment: _Как говорил Эйнштейн: "Всё относительно"_
Всё верно, забыл уточнить - нужно получить координаты видимой части элемента относительно окна. Спасибо за дополнительную информацию.

Comment: @rd2d2 В данной формулировке можно решить задачу аналогично поиску "габаритов" в пределах родительского элемента, только вместо его габаритов поставить `{left: 0, top: 0, right: window.innerWidth, bottom: window.innerHeight}`

Comment: Спасибо! Только вот как быть со скроллом? Может есть кроссбраузерный способ получить длинну и высоту окна без скролла?

Comment: Свойства `document.documentElement.clientWidth` и `document.documentElement.clientHeight` дают правильные значения в браузерах даже в IE6 (но только в strict-mode)